# Database vs XML File for minimal content

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sqlite

I am building a website for a client. The landing page has 4 areas of customizable content. The content is minimal, it's mainly just a reference to an image, an associated link, and an order...so 3 fields.

I am already using a lot of MySQL Tables for the other CMS related aspects, but for this one use, I am wondering if a database table really is the best option. The table would have only 4 records and there would be 3 columns. It's not going to be written too very often, just read from as the landing page loads.

Would I be better off sticking to a MySQL table for storing this minimal amount of information since it will fit into the [programming] workflow easy enough? Or would using an XML file that stores the information be a better way to go?

**UPDATE**: The end user (who knows nothing about databases) will be going through a web interface I create to choose one of the 4 items they want to update, then uploading an image from their computer, then selecting the link from a list of pages on the site (or offsite). The XML file or Database table will store the location of the image on the server and the link to wrap it in.

Comment: why dont you just create a template and use that instead. I am in favor of sticking with the db way atleast you can change it on the go if you have access to phpmyadmin from anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database is the correct solution for storing dynamic data. However I agree it sounds like MySQL is overkill for this situation. It also means an entire other thing to administer and manage. But using a flat-file like XML is a bad idea too. Luckily **SQLite** is just the thing.

Let these snippets from the [SQLite site](http://www.sqlite.org/features.html) encourage you:

> Rather than using fopen() to write XML or some proprietary format into disk files used by your application, use an SQLite database instead. You'll avoid having to write and troubleshoot a parser, your data will be more easily accessible and cross-platform, and your updates will be transactional.
>
> Because it requires no configuration and stores information in ordinary disk files, SQLite is a popular choice as the database to back small to medium-sized websites.

Read more [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

As for PHP code to interface with the database, use either [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or the specific SQLite [extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php).
PDO is more flexible so I'd go with that and it should work out of the box - "PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0." ([reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php)) Finding references and tutorials is super easy and just a search away.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this answer. I hadn't even thought of SQLite. I have come across references to it before, but I mainly stick to MySQL because I know it very well. SQLite looks pretty easy to implement. Not to mention SQL is easier to understand than using SimpleXML LIbrary in PHP. I am a little familiar with PDO. I use ezSQL for a lot of my database stuff, and it supports SQLite, so the interaction should be seamless.

Comment: ezSQL is just the thing. It doesn't matter really, especially since this is a straight-forward use case. You know MySQL; you know ezSQL; this will be a piece of cake. Using an XML parser will only bring complication ;-)

Comment: I worked many times with sqlite to make parte of static pages of custoemers dynamic. I habe never problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP the SimpleXML library could give you what you need and using XML in this fashion for something like you describe might be the simplest way to go. You don't have to worry about any MySQL configurations or worrying about the client messing something up. Restoring and maintaining an XML file might be easier too. The worry might be future scalability if you plan to grow the site much. That's my 2 cents anyway.

Comment: That's a good answer. The site is built on a MySQL Backbone and it is infinitely scalable. However, the landing page has 4 items that don't necessarily fit within the rest of the scope, that is why I am thinking of using XML instead of MySQL for that one item.

Comment: It sounds like it would work great for what you have in mind. You might read through the functions available and see if it covers your needs. http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php